# How to structure a project that dynamically calls a method of subclasses in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, data-structures, directory-structure

Say I have a base class with a method such as `render()`.

I have ~20 subclasses which inherit this base class and redefine the `render()` method. At the moment they are alllocated in a package in my project, with each defined in a seperate file. e.g.

```
__main__.py
baseclass.py -> BaseClass
myclasses
 | subclass1.py -> SubClass1(BaseClass)
 | subclass2.py -> SubClass2(BaseClass)
 | subclass3.py -> SubClass3(BaseClass)
 | ...etc
```

In my main program, I want to dynamically create instances of these subclasses and call the `render()` method on them. What is the most pythonic way to do this? Every implementation I've tried seems hacky - I've tried using wildcards and `__subclasses__()` but this doesn't play well with my linter/type checking. But also, I don't want 20 explicit imports at the top of my file (plus, my linter doesn't like this either).

Am I using the wrong data/file structure here? Is there a smart way to do this I am missing?

Comment: you should be able to iterate over a list of subclasses of Baseclass and call render() without checking anything... how did you attempt to do it? what didn't work?

Comment: @eagr It's not as simple as just calling __subclasses__() as the base class has no knowedge of the subclasses unless they are all imported into the module in some way.

Comment: What instance of which subclass needs to call ```render()```? Why would an instance need to know about children of the parent class that it is not inheriting from?

Comment: @jwal In main, I want to loop through all subclasses, creating an instance of every subclass and call `render()` on each instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension of a technique I've only used once. It's outside my area of expertise so there is room for improvement.

```
class Base(type):
    subclasses = []

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, namespace):
        super().__init__(name, bases, namespace)
        cls.subclasses.append(cls)


class Child1(metaclass=Base):
    def __init__(self, ver):
        self.ver = ver
    def render(self):
        print(f'{self.ver} render Child1')


class Child2(metaclass=Base):
    def __init__(self, ver):
        self.ver = ver
    def render(self):
        print(f'{self.ver} render Child2')


def main():
    for sub in Base.subclasses:         # iterate the classes
        subs.append(sub(0))             # create a new instance
        subs.append(sub(1))             # create another to prove class property
    """Iterate the classes calling render() on each one."""
    for sub in subs:
        sub.render()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
0 render Child1
1 render Child1
0 render Child2
1 render Child2
```